# Making links SEO friendly using JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a lot of trouble with blog post link creation. The point is that I want to have:
**website.com/blog/title-name** (title is a string that I am getting from the database) instead of:
**website.com/views/post.php?title=title-name**

Adding the main related code lines from the files:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($request) {
    case "/" :
        $title = "Home Page";
        $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/views/index.php');
        $active_page ='home';
        break;
    case "" :
        $title = "Home Page";
        $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/views/index.php');
        $active_page ='home';
        break;
    case "/blog" :
        $title = "Blog Page";
        $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/views/blog.php');
        $active_page ='blog';
        break;
    case "/contact" :
        $title = "Contact Page";
        $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/views/contact.php');
        $active_page ='contact';
        break;
    default:
        $title = "404 - Not found";
        http_response_code(404);
        $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/views/404.php');
        break;
}
?>
```

**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**./components/js/blog.js:**

```
// linking blog container
const titleLink = document.createElement("a");
titleLink.href = `/views/post.php?title=${encodeURIComponent(blogPost.title)}`;
```

**./views/post.php:**

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const postTitle = urlParams.get('title');
```

What I have tried to do is adding the following line to .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)$ /blog.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and changing the title link in blog.js to:

```
titleLink.href = `/blog/${blogPost.title}`;
```

But sadly that did not work.

Comment: What exactly did not work?

Comment: It is fetching 404 page, so I tried amending the request part of the default code to:
    default:
        if (strpos($request, "/blog/") === 0) {
            $title = "Blog Post";
            $active_page ='blog';
        } else {
            $title = "404 - Not found";
            http_response_code(404);
            $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/views/404.php');
        }
        break;

But still no result.

Comment: So do some basic debugging ... `var_dump($request, strpos($request, "/blog/"));` gets you what?

Comment: if its `/blog/title-name` inside `$request` its not going to be matched in  `case "/blog" :`, nor is `/blog.php?title=$1` going to hit `/views/post.php?title=title-name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was in the post.php file. You cannot use the title parameter since it was already changed in the .htaccess when landing on **/blog/post-title**. Instead the title in the link could be retrieved using something like:

```
const urlParts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
const title = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];
```

Accordingly the .htaccess should have:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)$ /blog.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```